# Почему NullPointerException, если тут никакой переменной не присваивается null? Как пофиксить?

Tags: java, android, исключения, io, null

```
GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
        Gson gson = builder.excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create();
        Context context1 = this;
//ИСКЛЮЧЕНИЕ ТУТ
        InputStreamReader inputRdr = new InputStreamReader(context1.openFileInput("cfg.json")); 
        JsonReader jsonRdr = new JsonReader(inputRdr);
        jsonRdr.setLenient(true);
        JsonElement jsonE = JsonParser.parseReader(jsonRdr);
        json = gson.fromJson(jsonRdr, Object.class);
        Toast.makeText(context, Home.Style + "HEY", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

`Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.FileInputStream android.content.Context.openFileInput(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference`

Откуда тут NullPointerException? Тут нигде не присваивается `null`.

Как исправить???

Answer (score 1):

Вызов на `null` происходит внутри `openFileInput`, потому что ваша активити - это `ContextWrapper`, в котором свой `Context`, которому делегируется вызов, а там `null`, скорее всего, потому что вы вручную создаёте активность `new MyActivity()`, чего делать нельзя, это должна делать система. Либо вызываете до присоединения внутреннего `Context` (в init блоке или контрукторе). Поэтому ответом будет не создавать вручную активити, а работу делать в `onCreate` или после него